BIM360 Issues - Get issue is empty when I apply fields=customAttributes
I am calling the endpoint:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/issues/v1/projects/:projectId/issues?fields=customAttributes 
But the response I get is lacking the information I need. Note that I am trying to access Autodesk Construction Cloud.
The response I receive looks like this:
{
    "pagination": {
        "limit": 100,
        "offset": 0,
        "totalResults": 19
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "some id",
            "title": "Issue 3",
            "issueTypeId": "some id",
            "status": "open",
            "ownerId": "some id",
            "customAttributes": []
        },
        {
            "id": "some id",
            "title": "Issue 4",
            "issueTypeId": "some id",
            "status": "open",
            "ownerId": "some id",
            "customAttributes": []
        }
.....

If I do not apply the fields=customAttributes then I receive a 'normal' response with all custom attributes along with the ids, values and titles.
I am following the documentation from here:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/

Is there some other way to retrieve the information I need by applying the fields in the query?

first, ACC Issue API and BIM360 Issue API are independent of each other. The title of your question is BIM360, but the description shows you are talking about ACC Issue API. I can reproduce the problem with ACC Issue API. I logged it with the ticket at ACC Issue API: SCCOM-23156 customAttributes returns [] if fields=customAttributes in the request param
